# Dynamic memory deallocating issue in c

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *mem(void){

  //int buf[]= {1,1,2,3};
  int *buf = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
  buf[1] = 1;

  return buf;
  free(buf);
}

int main(void){

  int *a[1] = { &mem()[1] };
    
  printf("%d", *a[0]};
  free(a[0]);
  return 0;

}
```

The output is 1, as expected but when I checked in Valgrind there is a memory leak which says 3 allocations and 2 frees. I don't want to use `static` here.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: Why do you put `free` before `return` in one function, but reversed in the other?

Comment: Your `a[0]` is actually `&buf[1]`. The proper way to free memory is to pass the exact value returned by the `malloc()` function to the `free()` function. Just for fun try `free(a[0] - sizeof(int));`

Comment: `free(buf)` is unreachable - have you remembered to enable a reasonable set of compiler warnings?  If you have, you probably need a better compiler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory leak should be a lesser concern here. Your program is invoking undefined behavior because you are freeing memory that's not been `malloc`d.

Add these 2 lines to your program to see what's up with the program:

```
printf("Returning %p\n", buf);
return buf;
```

and

```
printf("%d at %p\n", *a[0], a[0]);
free(a[0]);
```

Output should be something of the sorts:

```
Returning 0x602000000010
1 at 0x602000000014
```

And in the next call to `free` the address `0x602000000014` is passed in which is **not** the memory that was allocated in `mem()`. There's a full 4 byte difference between the memory that's being `free`d and the memory that was allocated owing to the size of `int` on my (and probably your) system i.e. `&buf[0]` and `&buf[1]` differ by 4 bytes.

Change your program to

```
int *a[1] = { &mem()[0] }; //point to the 0-th index of the returned buffer
printf("%d", a[0][1]); //get the 1-st index of the array pointed to by the a[0] pointer
```

To have the correct behavior. Also, one more thing. Statements after return aren't executed. That `free(buf)` is redundant in `mem()`.

EDIT: Here's the output after running valgrind after making the change:

```
$valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all  --track-origins=yes  --verbose  ./test

==3497== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3497==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3497==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 520 bytes allocated
==3497==
==3497== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3497==
==3497== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I did implement this but still the memory leak issue persists in valgrind saying there are 2 allocs and 1 free.

Comment: @Deekshagowda I pasted the valgrind output from the corrected program. What are the options that you are using for valgrind? Where does it still detect a leak? After correcting the program, there shouldn't be any leak. You allocated one memory block, and you free the memory block. What's the leak it points to? Does it point to any specific code location?

Comment: @Deekshagowda Also probably a dumb suggestion, but I hope you recompiled your program after making the change and used the new binary as Valgrind input?